# Need to optimize not in sql statement

Tags: sql, in-subquery

I have an sql query:

```
select person from table t1
inner join person_history ph
on t1.person = ph.person
and t1.person not in (select person from person_history 
                      where effective_date < '01-01-2013')
and ph.person.effective_date > '01-01-2013'
```

since `person_history` contains a lot of records, this query is taking too long.

How can I optimize this code?

Comment: What is this:  `and ph.person.effective_date > '01-01-2013'` that doesn't even seem like valid SQL.

Comment: Did you try to let your database `EXPLAIN` the query? That's usually a good way to find out why it's slow

Comment: What type of SQL is this?  Performance and tuning tends to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: What is ph.person.effective_date? person in the select should have t1 or ph.

Comment: You select {person*history} that is not in history. Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @syedmohsin: That can be legal in some dialects of SQL, such as postgres and mumps-based versions like Intersystems Cache`, I think.  In fact, it might even be legal in SQL Server with UDTs (not sure).

Comment: No. three level names can occur in Oracle and microsoft, I think. (Postgres maybe with remote connections)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do something like this:

```
select person from table t1
inner join person_history ph
on t1.person = ph.person
where ph.effective_date >= '01-01-2013'
```

Answer (score 1):

You needn't exclude the NOT IN as it is already excluded in the WHERE Filter!
the SQL will be simple as follows:

```
select person from table t1
inner join person_history ph on t1.person=ph.person
where effective_date > '01-01-2013'
```

Or:

```
select person from table t1
WHERE person IN(select ph.person from person_history ph
where effective_date > '01-01-2013' and t1.person=ph.person)
```